# d-i рецепт определения дисков для разбиения

Tags: linux, debian, raid, install, partition

Вечер добрый.

Составляю рецепт автоматической конфигурации установки для Ubuntu server 16.04 на основе Debian-Installer preseed

Стоит задача определить диск (RAID-1 и RAID-5 на физическом контролере) до момента разбиения на разделы изходя из его размера.

RAID-1 ~ 256G желаемвй диск для установки

RAID-5 ~ 10-16T диск беблиотеки, которая монтируется после установки системы, уже содержит данные, которые не должны пострадать.

```
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string
```

здесь будет рецепт на разбиение диска

```
/boot 100-1024
[SWAP] 2048-200% of mem
/ min 100G max 120G
свободное место до конца диска
```

Установщик слетает с автоматического режима и просит выбрать тип разбиения и диск

```
 d-i partman/early_command string
```

Ищу волшебные заклинания для этого параметра...

Если подскажете, где можно найти подробную документацию debian-installer буду благодарен!

Ссылки

- https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/example-preseed.txt
- https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed
- https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apbs05.html.en

---

**UP**

Пока нисал пост, нашел сырое решение

https://askubuntu.com/questions/707327/use-preseed-to-chose-install-disks-based-on-size-or-type